# Determining the dimension of the Eigenspace without knowing the eigenvalues (Segre Classification)

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials, invariant-theory

This has been a burning problem in my head for a while now. Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated. I'll use a concrete 3x3 matrix as an example, but I'd like to know thoughts especially for 4x4 and, if possible NxN matrices as well. The question originally popped into my head while I was learning about the Segre Classification of spacetimes.

Given a 3x3 matrix $A$

$A=\begin{bmatrix} a1 & a2 & a3 &\\a4 & a5 & a6 \\a7 & a8 & a9\end{bmatrix}$.

or possibly a symmetric matrix $B$ (whichever things can be said about. I'd like to know both cases if possible)

$B=\begin{bmatrix} b1 & b2 & b3 &\\b2 & b4 & b5 \\b3 & b5 & b6\end{bmatrix}$.

The question is: **Is it possible to determine the dimension of the eigenspace from some relation of the a's or b's?** (Various hopeful clarifications are given below)

For example, I know that I can determine repeated roots (repeated eigenvalues) from just looking at the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial. That's one thing done in the Segre classification. I'd like to extend this idea and know if there are any invariants which characterize the sizes of Jordan blocks/dimensions of the eigenspaces which I can just calculate from $A$ or $B$ or powers of each. The trouble I have been having is the minimal polynomial which would normally determine some of this depends on the eigenvalues which change as a1...a9 etc are varied. The easiest example here that I can think of is:

$\tilde{A}=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0 &\\0 & 2 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$.

Where the minimal polynomial is $(\lambda-2)^3$. But if I perturb a1->a1+epsilon, this instantly breaks and the minimal polynomial changes. Nevertheless, I believe there should be something in terms of the a's or b's to calculate out when exactly this happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be a way to find such a relation, however, it seems that it is much easier to determine the type of information you are looking for through invariant theory. Many of these types of questions can be answered through that lens. For example the question you presented can be converted in some sense to finding the algebraic invariants of a quadratic binary form in variables x,y. Depending on the invariants, certain aspects of the Jordan form (algebraic, and geometric multiplicity for example) are determined by the values: +,-, or 0 of these invariants. For an explicit example, the discriminant of a homogeneous binary form will influence the Jordan form of the 3x3 matrix you presented above.